# hive 1.1 take out hierarchy value from three tables

Tags: scala, hive

I have the following tables in HIVE (1.1 version) and need the output as shown in the Result. As UNION is not available in hive 1.1, need different approach to get the below result.

Table A:

id   name
1    One
2    Two
4    Four

Table B:

id name
1  ONE
3  THREE
4  FOUR

Table C:

id name
1  one
2  two
3  three
5  five

Result

id name
1  One
2  Two
3  THREE
4  Four
5  five

Answer (score 0):

select id, name from A 
UNION ALL
SELECT sec.id, sec.name FROM B sec WHERE sec.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM A) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT thr.id, thr.name FROM c thr  WHERE thr.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM A UNION ALL SELECT id FROM B)